# i have a issue to rewrite the url for the wordpress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, wordpress-theming

i have worpress site where links in this form 
http://www.example.com/?page_id=24
and 
http://www.example.com/?page_id=258&catid=45

I don't know to resolve this issue.

Comment: i want to change these into http//www.examaple.com/admin

Comment: i also have category of proudcts and these had pagination how to create link for thrme http//www.example.com/book/2

Answer (score 0):

You can change your links in the dashboard under Settings -> Permalinks

The best choice of links for search optimization is Post name which I believe is the link type you are looking for.

Comment: I m unable to do in this way .. how can do it with .htacess

Comment: If your .htaccess file cannot be accessed by Wordpress it will tell you at the bottom of the Permalinks settings menu with the code you have to paste in.

Answer (score 0):

Simply go to your dashboard by logging into your WordPress site. And then hover on the `settings` menu link and click on `permalinks`. Once there click on `Post  Name`. Then scroll down and click save changes.